# convert big number to string without scientific notation

Tags: javascript

e.g.`Number.MAX_VALUE.toString()` is `"1.7976931348623157e+308"`

I hope there is no `e+308`,How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
var n = Number.MAX_VALUE.toString();
var parts = n.split("e+");
var first = parts[0].replace('.', "");
var zeroes = parseInt(parts[1], 10) - (first.length - 1);
for(var i = 0; i < zeroes; i++){ first += "0"; }
// => first === "179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: BEWARE: This solution has bug and will not format correctly all strings like ex. "5.5".